# $y$ centralizes $fzf^{-1} $ for some $f \in F(G)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, solvable-groups, frobenius-groups

Let $G$ be a finite and soluble group with a trivial center. We assume that $C_G(x_r)$ acts free of fixed points on $F(G)$ by conjugation and $C_G(x_r)F(G)$ is a Frobenius group with complement $C_G(x_r)$ and nucleus $F(G)$, where $x_r$ is an element of prime order. Suppose that $C_G(x_r)$ has even order. So $C_G(x_r)$ has a single $z$ element of order $2$ and satisfies:
$$
f=zf^{-1}z\, \text{ for all } f\in F(G),  
\quad 
F(G) \text{ is abelian,} 
\quad
\text{and } z\in Z(C_G(x_r)).
$$

Consider another element $y \in G$ of odd order such that $C_{F(G)}(y)=1$.

I managed to ensure that there is a $\{2,|y|\}$-subgroup of $\operatorname{Hall}$ $H$ of $F(G)\langle z\rangle \langle y\rangle$ such that $y\in H$. I wonder if there is any result that guarantees that there is $f\in F(G)$ such that $[y,fzf^{-1}]=1$.

Comment: From your previous question, there exists $f \in F(G)$ with $yf \in C_G(z)$. The fact that $y$ centralizes no element of $F$ implies that $y$ and $yf$ are conjugate by an element of $f$, which implies the result you want.

Comment: because the fact that $[y,f']\neq 1$ for all $f'\in F(G)$, follows that $y$ and $yf$ are conjugated by an element of $F(G)$?

Comment: Yes, the elements $f^{-1}yf$ for $f \in F$ are all different, so there are $|F|$ of them, and they all lie in the coset $yF$, which also has size $|F|$.

Comment: Thank you so much, now I get it! Nor did it need the existence of the ${2,|y|}$-Hall subgroup.